# Asymptotics of a logarithmic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the following integral as $m \rightarrow \infty$:

$$\int_2 ^{\sqrt{m}} \frac{m-x^2}{x \mbox{ ln } x}\mbox{d}x $$

Specifically, I already know that the first term behaves like $\mathcal{O}(m \mbox{ ln } (\mbox{ ln } m))$ because we can just evaluate the integral, but I'm not sure about the other part. Is the entire integral still $\mathcal{O}(m \mbox{ ln } (\mbox{ ln } m))$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting problem (+1). Are you supposed to know about  the exponential integral function ?

Comment: I appreciate your attention. No, we are not supposed to know about it. I looked it up and it seems to be related to this integral, but I can't figure out the details. This integral is related to estimating the cost of a prime sieve.

Comment: The integral does not converge if the lower limit is $1$. Are you sure the lower limit is $1$?

Comment: Oh, I'll make it a 2 then. I only care about the asymptotics for large $m$ anyways.

Comment: According to mathematica, this equals `-m Log[Log[4]] + m Log[Log[m]] + LogIntegral[4] - LogIntegral[m]`

Comment: $ \int_{e}^{\sqrt{m}} x/\ln x \le \int_e^{\sqrt{m}} x = O(m),$ so the stated integral is $m \ln \ln m - O(m)$

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Let $x=e^y$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{m-x^2}{x \,\log(x)}\,dx=\int\frac{m-e^{2 y}}{y}\,dy=\int\frac{m}{y}\,dy-2\int\frac{e^{2 y}}{2y}\,dy$$ that is to say
$$I=m \log (y)-\text{Ei}(2 y)$$ where appears [the exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Now, the asymptotics
$$\text{Ei}(t)=e^t
   \left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\right)$$ 
Since we are bargaining, let me use a lower bound equal to $e$
Back to $x$, then
$$J=\int_e^{\sqrt m} \frac{m-x^2}{x \,\log(x)}\,dx=m \log
   \left(\log \left(\sqrt{m}\right)\right)-\text{Ei}\left(2 \log \left(\sqrt{m}\right)\right)+\text{Ei}(2)$$ Just play now with the asymptotics.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a reference for the asymptotic expansion of $\mbox{Ei}(t)$? And, if I plug this into the result for $J$ then I indeed obtain that the entire integral behaves as I expected, right?

Comment: @ThomasBakx. Have a look at https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12#i  . By the way, you are welcome ! Cheers :-)